# Gardening produce - fertilizer with blood meal, kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, fruits, vegetables

So as I'm getting ready to grow citrus trees and veggies, I went on the hunt for fertilizers (individual household, not a commercial farmer). I noticed that a whole lot of fertilizers use an ingredient called blood meal and chicken bones. I understand why those ingredients are there, but would these ingredients render the fruit/veggies not kosher if used or are they still kosher?

Comment: possible duplicate of... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44664/why-does-the-use-of-horse-manure-as-fertilizer-not-make-produce-non-kosher?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

See Mishna Yoma 5, 6:

> הִזָּה עַל טָהֳרוֹ שֶׁל מִזְבֵּחַ שֶׁבַע פְּעָמִים, וּשְׁיָרֵי הַדָּם הָיָה שׁוֹפֵךְ עַל יְסוֹד מַעֲרָבִי שֶׁל מִזְבֵּחַ הַחִיצוֹן, וְשֶׁל מִזְבֵּחַ הַחִיצוֹן הָיָה שׁוֹפֵךְ עַל יְסוֹד דְּרוֹמִי. אֵלּוּ וָאֵלּוּ מִתְעָרְבִין בָּאַמָּה וְיוֹצְאִין לְנַחַל קִדְרוֹן, וְנִמְכָּרִין לַגַּנָּנִין לְזֶבֶל, וּמוֹעֲלִין בָּהֶן׃
>
> and poured out the remainder of the blood at the western base of the outer altar, and [the remainder of the blood sprinkled] on the outer altar he poured out at the southern base.  Both mingled in the canal and flowed into the brook Kidron and they were sold to gardeners as manure and by using them one transgresses the law of trespass {rabbinically, Gemara 59b}.

You see clearly that the blood is used to fertilize gardens and the fruits of the garden are allowed.

This is a proof from a Mishna, but perhaps there is no need of proof. Because the blood decomposes before the absorption by plants. Blood, as most prohibited aliments, is not prohibited for profit. E.g., a non-ritually killed casher animal is allowed for dog food. Chelev (a kind of prohibited adipose tissue) is allowed for candles. A casher fish eats a lot of non-casher fishes and is allowed for food because the non-casher fishes are digested in its body.